# Is there search software for text that contains specific words?

Tags: resource-request, english, software

To give an example. Here is a list of suggested words and phrases which students should learn: [Primary Stage - Levels 1, 2, 3, 4 (P1, P2, P3, P4)](http://ncp.ge/en/inglisuri-ena/datskebiti-safekhuri-done-i-ii-iii-iv-di-dii-diii-div)  (The Portal of National Curriculum, Georgia; Creative Commons License).

I'm looking for a search software that would look through different online texts (novels, news, poems, you name it) and find ones where most of the words are present (well, not all words from that page, say I make sub-list of 30 words).

Additional features that would be great to have:

- Filter text by readability index.
- Chose the type of medium (text, audio, video).

Comment: Are you interested in a particular language (as in the example) or generally? Should it process files of specific file type (.txt, .pdf, .doc) or perhaps look for the words online?

Comment: Google search allows you to restrict the search to a certain website. So you can find a website with graded text for reading, and search it for the words from your list. It is unlikely that anyone wrote a tool to do that - but it could be a fun semester project for some programming student.

Comment: @TommiBrander, yes, English. Look online.

Comment: @PeterM., thanks for suggestion. Yes, there might be some work arounds, but I'm interested if there is a spefic tool for this.

Comment: Google has syntax that allows you to search for exact strings.  Some of it is available in the advanced search